# .htaccess : write rule with langage parameter for SEO

Tags: .htaccess

The goa is to rewrite:

```
www.example.com/fr/something.php ->www.example.com/something.php?lang=fr
```

I tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/fr/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?lang=fr[R,L]


RewriteRule \/fr\/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?lang=fr[R,L,QSA]

RewriteRule /fr/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?lang=fr[R,L,QSA]
```

Not good: 
Any idea ?

Comment: Lose the `.*/` in the beginning; you don't want anything before the `/fr`. And try with or without a `/` in the beginning, I forgot which one is needed there. The rest looks OK (although you probably want to add `QSA`: `[R,L,QSA]` so you can pass on any query parameters

Comment: I tried MANY combinations. It looks like my regex is bad

Comment: What exactly happens when you enter the URL?

Comment: Did you try `RewriteRule fr/` etc. etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /$1?lang=fr [QSA,L]
```

I do not think you want a redirect, but only a rewrite (without changing the url)